# How to append to bash history before showing the prompt if the line isn't a duplicate?

Tags: bash

Because it seems often the history isn't saved when shutting down and not closing gnome terminal, I'd like to append to bash history before showing the prompt if the line isn't a duplicate. Although I have `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` in .bashrc, which is supposed to imply ignoredups, it doesn't seem to work, as I still get duplicates in bash_history. So how to do this?

To offer further indications, although not solutions:
I think $PROMPT_COMMAND needs to have `"$(history 1)" (if_not_duplicate) >> ~/.bash_history`

But $(history 1) needs to be changed so the actual command gets output, not the history entry, which, for instance, has line numbers.

And this would remove non-adjacent duplicates, if they are already inserted.

```
perl -nei '$H{$_}++ or print' ~/.bash_history
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `erasedups` too if you want to remove duplicates from the history.

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
```

does the trick for me.

Comment: But $(history 1) needs to be changed so the actual command gets output, not the history entry, which, for instance, has line numbers.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you're saying, but if you want to save the history after each command, `history -w` does that.

Comment: So adding history -w to $PROMPT_COMMAND will append the latest command to history?

Comment: No, it will save the full history. And if you have `erasedups` set, it will remove duplicates. Which ends up doing what you want.

Comment: That seems inefficient. Is there a way to just append the last command if it's not a duplicate?

Comment: To determine whether you need to do dup removal from the file correctly, you need to read the whole file anyway, so it's in cache. The write won't hit the disk most of the time - and appending will need to re-write the whole last block of the file anyway. So...

Comment: history -w, when enabled, actually seems to truncate .bash_history, maybe on starting gnome terminal. When I disabled it, .bash_history was no longer being truncated.

Comment: Try `history -a` or `-aw` perhaps.

Comment: Neither of those work. history -aw also results in "bash: history: cannot use more than one of -anrw."